# Call to a member function bind_param() on null / while update query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-update

After I've tried many things that I have found on Google and here on stackoverflow I can't solve my problem.
So I decided to ask the community.

This is my PHP code for getting the post form:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $firstPW = $_POST['password'];
    $secondPW = $_POST['repassword'];

    //DEBUG VARIABLES AREN'T NULL.
    echo nl2br(trim($firstPW) . "\n" . trim($secondPW) . "\n" . $email . "\n" . trim($token) . "\n");

    if ($firstPW == $secondPW) {
        $pwunequal = FALSE;

        $hashedpass = password_hash(trim($firstPW), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));
        // PASSWORD HASH ISN'T NULL
        echo nl2br(trim($hashedpass) . "\n");

        // $con is defined in another file which is required at the top.
        $ustmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET `Password` = ? WHERE Email = ?");
        if ($ustmt !== FALSE) {
            $ustmt->bind_param("ss", $hashedpass, $email);
            $ustmt->execute();

            echo  "Successfully updated.";
            $ustmt->close();
            $con->close();
        } else {
            echo "NULL";
        }
    } else {
        $pwunequal = TRUE;
    }
}
```

When I submit the form I get the following output:

```
Value of $firstPW
Value of $secondPW
Value of $email (got email through $_GET[] before)
Value of $hashedpass

Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli on line 49
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on null on line 51
```

None of the above is null.

My database setup:

```
The column "Password" = varchar(200), collation = utf8_general_ci, not null, default none
The column "Email" = varchar(200), collation = utf8_general_ci, not null, default none
```

I hope someone can spot my mistake, 'cause I can't find it myself. :/
Every helpful comment is much appreciated.

Comment: If `mysqli::prepare()` fails you should check that one. Show us how you set up `$con`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood the error message...

The variable *$ustmt* problably is null and you can't call the function *bind_param()* on it. It seems the case as the *$conn->prepare()* raised a warning and seems not to be executed correctly.

Maybe you should extend your if clause a little bit:

```
if(isset($ustmt) && $ustmt !== FALSE)
```

Comment: Hey marcellorvalle,

thank you very much, I have found my error.  
I accidently closed the connection via $con->close(); in the $_GET[] part of the code. The code is working now.